# Additional mass of block on inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

I would like some help in solving this problem.

[image: Height is 15 cm , base is 88 cm]

Height is 15 cm , base is 88 cm

My attempt:
$$(119.3 + m)(\sin(\theta)) = (88*9.8)$$
$$ 15^2 + 88^2 = 89.269^2 $$

$$ \sin^{-1} = 15/89.269 $$

$$ (119.3 + m)(9.6733) = (88*9.8) $$

$m = -30.14$ ....Am I missing something? I feel like it has something to do with the force of friction...

Comment: Brother, theta is spelled wrong. Further, friction does not alter the fundamental components of mass and the forces of gravity

Comment: I didn't make the photo...

Comment: Fair enough. Can you tell me anything else? Like distances, heights, etc? I can follow your work I think but I dont want to assume values. For example, what is theta?

Comment: Height: 15 cm
Base: 88 cm
Theta: unknown
Friction: negligible? I assume because of the cloth.

Comment: Ok cool, one sec

Comment: Justin, I editted your post to use MathJax formatting for the equations. Please check that they still represent what you were trying to say. Also it's better to define and use symbols for everything, otherwise a bunch of numbers just come out of nowhere and it's hard for others to know what's happening. For instance, in your first equation I'm guessing the 9.8 is the acceleration of gravity measured in $m/s^2$. If so, you have a mass on the left hand side and a force on the right hand side so the equation doesn't make sense dimensionally.

Comment: @Justin, Do you know what [Free Body Diagrams](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/newtlaws/u2l2c.cfm) are?

Comment: Thanks for showing your work Justin. In your original work I believe you did not cancel a factor of $g$ and did not evaluate the sine properly. The cloth is a ruse to get you to ignore friction effects. Friction problems of this caliber will usually tell you how to obtain friction or just give you a coefficient of friction.

Comment: $$ 15^2 + 88^2 = 89.269^2 $$  how you got 89.269?

Comment: Any progress on this problem? Could you either tell us that your problem is solved, still open or something else?

Comment: Yes, I solved this problem quite awhile ago. I marked the post below as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin,

So first off you know that if you have a base of 88 cm and a height of 15 cm on an inclined plane, we have $$\sin(\theta)=\frac{15}{x}$$ where $x= \sqrt{88^{2}+15^{2}}$. Solving, we obtain $\theta \approx 9.673$ degrees. We set up our equation, $$m_{bear}g=m_{box}g\sin(\theta)$$ Because we want the forces to cancel so the bear does not reach an unfortunate end. We then say $$88kg = (119.3+x)\sin(9.673)$$ and solve for x. I obtained $x \approx 404.3 kg$, so we would need to add an extra 400 kg to prevent the bear's fiery fate.

Comment: Admittedly, bear is pretty good.

Comment: Thank you!
I see where I went wrong. >.<

"(119.3 + m)sin(9.6733) = (88*9.8)" <---I forgot about the gravitational acceleration.

Comment: In accordance with our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714), I'm temporarily deleting this.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a diagram with forces:

http://wstaw.org/m/2013/02/12/mixed2.png

Now we have $F_\text{box} = m_\text{box} g$ where $g$ is your gravitational acceleration with value $9.81\,\text{m/s^2}$.

The trick is now to separate the force of the into a parallel part $F_\parallel$ to the slope and another part $F_\perp$ perpendicular to the slope. The part $F_\perp$ will not contribute to the force on the rope, just the $F_\parallel$ part will do. Using trigonometry for the angle $\vartheta$, this force is:
$$
F_{\text{box},\parallel} = F_\text{box} \sin(\vartheta) = m_\text{box} g \sin(\vartheta)
$$

Now this force has to be exactly the same magnitude as the force on the bear, which is $F_\text{bear}$:
$$
F_{\text{box},\parallel} = F_\text{bear}
$$

We plug in what we have so far:
$$
m_\text{box} g \sin(\vartheta) = m_\text{bear} g
$$

We cancel the $g$:
$$
m_\text{box} \sin(\vartheta) = m_\text{bear}
$$

Since your $m_\text{bear}$ is given and $\vartheta$ has to be given and we want to know the mass that the box needs to have, we can solve this equation for $m_\text{box}$ like so:
$$
m_\text{box} = \frac{m_\text{bear}}{\sin(\vartheta)}
$$

I see that $\vartheta$ is given implicitly. You have $$\tan(\vartheta) = \frac{\text{height}}{\text{base}}$$

You can then solve this for $\vartheta$:
$$\vartheta = \arctan\left(\frac{\text{height}}{\text{base}}\right)$$

Put this into the above equation:
$$
m_\text{box} = \frac{m_\text{bear}}{\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\text{height}}{\text{base}}\right)\right)}
$$

Now you can put in all your numbers. If you subtract the mass you will get from the mass that you already have, you know how much more to add. If it is negative, you can even take mass away from the box and the bear will still be saved.